# Testing node.js with jest: Cannot spy the save property because it is not a function

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, sequelize.js, nest

I am testing a sequelize model with jest and I am getting this error

> Cannot spy the save property because it is not a function; undefined
> given instead

save is a builtin method in sequelize so I am wondering why I am getting this error

my test is:

```
describe('...', () => {
    it('...', () => {
        jest.spyOn(model, 'save');
        ...
    });
});
```

and my function is:

```
generateToken() {
    return generateTokenHash(20)
             .then((token) => {
                  this.token = token;
                  return this.save();
             });
}
```

If I remove this line `jest.spyOn(model, 'save');` I get error but in model's function `TypeError: this.save is not a function`

Comment: What does `this` in `this.token` refers to?

Comment: this is instance of model `generateToken ` is a method in model

Comment: Then try to print the `model.save` to check what it is.